ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications -- LastPass
I have narrowed down this error as happening in our React application within input type='text' elements but ONLY for users using the LastPass web browser extension. It happens when a user is on a page/route with at least one input element on it and then attempts to navigate to a separate page/route.
The error doesn't really 'break' things necessarily, but it is a nuisance in that its the number 1 issue reported by our issue tracker Sentry. Webpack will catch it when we are running locally, but other than that its just going to throw an error in the browser console.
We don't use resize observer at all in our own code and I can successfully re-create this issue by toggling the LastPass extension on and off in my own browser. On I get the error, Off and the error goes away.
And its not ALL text inputs, but as far as I can tell LastPass tries to guess which inputs would need an auto-fill option (email, name, phone, address, etc.) which ends up being a lot of inputs inside our application (creating or updating a user, creating or updating an organization, etc.) that aren't associated with authentication at all so that is really annoying.
I've reviewed numerous other SO questions and other discussions across other online forums on this issue. The most recent one was here: React: ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications
Historically, there have been several different ways to disable LastPass from popping up on these input elements (autocomplete="off", data-lpignore="true", changing type to 'search' or having 'search' in id, etc.), but it appears that the only reliable way currently is to go into the advanced settings of the LastPass extension itself and set the "Respect AutoComplete=off: allow websites to disable Autofill" setting. Each of the users of our application would have to do that individually and that is just not a solution in my opinion.
Kind of just shooting my shot here, but hoping to figure out a way to resolve this issue, if it is even possible.
I've already tried disabling LastPass from popping up in our inputs in every way I could find online, I've tried just completely setting the LastPass icon element itself as 'display: none', and I've even tried playing around with the width/height/dimensions of the input element itself to see if that might help, but just stuck at this point.
